# Canonical links for domain/ & domain/index.html

Tags: canonical-link

Is there any way fix this error or is it a page speed insights bug?

> Document does not have a valid `rel=canonical`
> Points to the domain's root URL (the homepage), instead of an equivalent page of content

URLS are different but all will resolve to the same page

- https://swimmingpoolslides.net/
- https://swimmingpoolslides.net/index.html
- https://www.swimmingpoolslides.net

I have no idea what to try.